# Singular integral bounded by Dirichlet form?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis

We define for some fixed $L$
$$\Omega:=\{(x_1,x_2) \in ([-L,L]^2 \times [-L,L]^2)  \setminus \{x_1=x_2\}\},$$
in particular $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R^2.$
Let $f \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, then I am wondering if we have the bound for some universal $C$ depending only on $\Omega$
$$ \int_{\Omega} \frac{\vert f(x)\vert^2}{\vert x_1-x_2 \vert^2} \ dx_1 \ dx_2 \le C (\Vert f \Vert^2_{L^2} + \Vert \nabla f \Vert^2_{L^2}).$$

At first there seems to be an issue with the integral on the left-hand side namely that $1/|x|^2$ is not integrable in two dimensions, so any $f(x)=g(x_1-x_2)$ with $g(0)\neq 0$ would yield infinity on the left-hand side. So one might try to approximate such $f$ by $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega).$

However, the expression on the right-hand side is the Dirichlet form and thus anything I can expect to get in the limit should vanish somehow on $\{x_1=x_2\},$ i.e. has to be in $H_0^1(\Omega).$ I am however not even sure if the left-hand side makes sense for objects in $H_0^1(\Omega).$

Comment: This seems similar (at least in spirit) to your earlier question, which I found interesting. Is there a reason you deleted this?

Comment: @ChristianRemling I think it is because I was struggling to find the right way of phrasing my question and thought this was more likely to be true.

Comment: @ChristianRemling now the question is hopefully phrased in a suitable way https://mathoverflow.net/questions/465888/schroedinger-operator-in-2-dimensions-with-singular-potential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Om}{\Omega}$The answer is no.

Indeed, by rescaling, without loss of generality $L=1$. Suppose that
\begin{equation}
f(x_1,x_2)=g_a(x_1-x_2) 
\end{equation}
for $(x_1,x_2)\in\Om$,
where $g_a\in W^{1,2}((-2,2)^2)$ with support in $[-1,1]^2$ such that
$g_a(u):=|u|^a$ for a real $a>0$ and all $u\in(-1/2,1/2)^2$.

So, if your inequality were true, then we would have
\begin{equation*}
    L(a):=\int_{(-1,1)^2} \frac{g_a(u)^2}{|u|^2}\,du \\ 
    \le C_1 \int_{(-1,1)^2} (g_a(u)^2+|\nabla g_a(u)|^2)\,du=:R(a)  \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
for some real $C_1>0$ and all real $a>0$.

However, for $a\downarrow0$ we have $L(a)\asymp1/a$ whereas $R(a)\asymp1$, and hence \eqref{1} fails to hold.

Comment: thanks, though $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R^2$ in my case? It seems you covered the case $x_1 \in \mathbb R$? I have to confess $x_1,x_2$ was probably not the best notation, sorry about that!

Comment: Yes, your two-dimensional case reduces to the one-dimensional one. Do you want me to provide details on this?

Comment: if you would not mind, absolutely!

Comment: thank you for your answer anyway already, but the reduction to the 1D case that you are not using is not quite evident to me, but maybe it is also due to the use of $u$ both as the 1D variable and the difference $x_1-x_2 \in \mathbb R^2.$

Comment: @AntónioBorgesSantos : I have added the details.

Comment: sorry that ask this again, but if $x_1-x_2 \in \mathbb R^2$, then why do you say that $u,v \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: @AntónioBorgesSantos : Sorry, I misread your question -- did not notice that you square $[-L,L]$. I'll try to see if this answer can be appropriately modified.

Comment: Since it seems you have a lot of intuition for this. Do you think the answer to my question could be positive if I replace the gradient by the Laplacian on the right hand side?

Comment: @AntónioBorgesSantos : I would have to think about the Laplacian.

Comment: @ChristianRemling : That is for dimension $n=1$. For $n=2$, any $a>0$ will do --  [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Examples).

Comment: @IosifPinelis there is now an extension of the question in a more operator theoretic framework https://mathoverflow.net/questions/465888/schroedinger-operator-in-2-dimensions-with-singular-potential

Comment: @AntónioBorgesSantos : I will look at that question.

Comment: @ChristianRemling : Those were some typos, kind of, and they should now be fixed. Thank you for your comments.